# openerp search view hidden

Tags: search, view, odoo, hidden, invisible

I have a TransientModel which reads from an external data base, thus i created model with functional fields and also declared the search function.

This is a partial column declaration:

```
    _columns = {
        'web_id': fields.function(_get_data, string='ID', fnct_search=_search_data, type='integer', method=True, multi='external'),
 .....
    }
```

The action for the tree view is

```
<record id="action_preview_orders" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Preview Orders</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">external.data</field>
    <field name="view_type">tree</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="preview_orders_view"/>
    <field name="target">current</field>
    <field name="search_view_id" ref="preview_orders_view_filters"/>
</record>
```

and the search view is

```
<record id="preview_orders_view_filters" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Preview Filters</field>
    <field name="model">external.data</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search string="Search Orders">
    <filter string="Type" icon="terp-accessories-archiver" domain="[('type_order','=','RO')]"/>
       </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

data are showed correctly, my problem is that the search form is not displayed.
It is present into the html, but the div has style=display:hidden

What could I possibly did wrong?

I add the get data function as asked, it is highly dynamic.
I don't know if this could be a problem...

```
    def _get_data(self, cr, uid, ids, field_names, arg, context=None):
    res = dict.fromkeys(ids)
    for k in ids:
        res[k] = dict.fromkeys(self._mapper.keys())
        for mk in self._mapper.keys():
            fmt = self._mapper[mk].get('format', None)
            fnc = self._mapper[mk].get('function', None)
            params = self._mapper[mk].get('parameters', None)
            if params != None:
                indexes = [INDEXES[param] for param in params]
                values = [self._rows[k][index] for index in indexes]
                if fmt != None:
                    res[k][mk] = fmt.format(*values)
                elif fnc != None:
                    res[k][mk] = fnc(self, cr, uid, *values)
                else:
                    res[k][mk] = ""
            else:
                res[k][mk] = ""
    return res
```

the search function is a dummy one:

```
    def _search_data(self, cr, uid, obj, name, args, context):
        return [('id','in',[0])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create function _search_data **(for fnct_search=_search_data)**

```
def _get_full_name(self, cr, uid, ids, field, arg, context=None):
    res = {}
    for g in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context):
        if g.category_id:
            res[g.id] = '%s / %s' % (g.category_id.name, g.name)
        else:
            res[g.id] = g.name
    return res

def _search_group(self, cr, uid, obj, name, args, context=None):
    operand = args[0][2]
    operator = args[0][1]
    lst = True
    if isinstance(operand, bool):
        domains = [[('name', operator, operand)], [('category_id.name', operator, operand)]]
        if operator in expression.NEGATIVE_TERM_OPERATORS == (not operand):
            return expression.AND(domains)
        else:
            return expression.OR(domains)
    if isinstance(operand, basestring):
        lst = False
        operand = [operand]
    where = []
    for group in operand:
        values = filter(bool, group.split('/'))
        group_name = values.pop().strip()
        category_name = values and '/'.join(values).strip() or group_name
        group_domain = [('name', operator, lst and [group_name] or group_name)]
        category_domain = [('category_id.name', operator, lst and [category_name] or category_name)]
        if operator in expression.NEGATIVE_TERM_OPERATORS and not values:
            category_domain = expression.OR([category_domain, [('category_id', '=', False)]])
        if (operator in expression.NEGATIVE_TERM_OPERATORS) == (not values):
            sub_where = expression.AND([group_domain, category_domain])
        else:
            sub_where = expression.OR([group_domain, category_domain])
        if operator in expression.NEGATIVE_TERM_OPERATORS:
            where = expression.AND([where, sub_where])
        else:
            where = expression.OR([where, sub_where])
    return where

_columns = {
    'full_name': fields.function(_get_full_name, type='char', string='Group Name', fnct_search=_search_group),
}
```

check out full name in res.groups table

Comment: I already did one, a dummy one:     def _search_data(self, cr, uid, obj, name, args, context):
        return [('id','in',[0])]

Comment: you have to use it based on your search data coz the data is not stored in the table, so u need get data from the corresponding table for search also post your _get_data  here to understand better

Comment: I added it into my original post

Comment: _get_data is ok but what about fnct_search=_search_data

Comment: ther search function is a dummy one (I just edited the question to include it) but I don't see how it is possible that a dummy search function can provoke the search view to be hidden: I put a breakpoint inside and it is not called at all!

Answer (score 0):

```
def _get_full_name(self, cr, uid, ids, field, arg, context=None):
    res = {}
    for g in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context):
        if g.partner_id.new_ic_number:
            res[g.id] = g.partner_id.new_ic_number
        elif g.partner_id.old_ic_number:
            res[g.id] = g.partner_id.old_ic_number
            #~ res[g.id] = '%s / %s' % (g.category_id.name, g.name)
        else:
            res[g.id] = ''
    return res

def _search_customer_ic(self, cr, uid, obj, name, args, context=None):
    ids = set()
    partner_obj = self.pool.get('res.partner')
    partner_ids1 = partner_obj.search(cr,uid,[('new_ic_number','ilike',args[0][2])])
    partner_ids2 = partner_obj.search(cr,uid,[('old_ic_number','ilike',args[0][2])])
    partner_ids = partner_ids1+partner_ids2
    partner_ids = list(set(partner_ids))
    agreement_ids = self.search(cr,uid,[('partner_id','in',partner_ids)])
    return  [('id','in',agreement_ids)]
_columns = {
'ic_number':fields.function(_get_full_name, type='char', string='Customer IC', fnct_search=_search_customer_ic),
  }
```

This is sample code which is done to retreive customer_ic number based search in agreement table(custom table) where we have partner_id and no ic number ,so i retrieve data from **res.partner** (***old_ic_number or new_ic_number*** and same  functional field by *search* method to search in agreement table